# how to enable nunit log with connection to visual studio project

Tags: nunit

i have a test in visual studio with reference to nunit dll and containning for example :

```
[TestFixture(Description = "Test"), Category("")]
    class Try
 [Test]
        public void TC1()
        {
          Debug.Write("first Test");
          Trace.Write("Only Example)
        }
```

how can i enable nunit log?
is it possible to save a log in Specific Directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you debug in Visual Studio, your Debug and Trace write statements will show up in the output window. This has nothing special to do with NUnit.

NUnit does have an internal trace log, but it only records... internal stuff. :-)